# New to Mathematica - Finding 5 roots

Tags: equation-solving

I'm very new to Mathematica and I'm trying to find a way to find 5 roots for the following:

xtan(x)=1

and

sin^2(πx)-x^2*cos(πx)=x

I feel that it's a simple solution but I'm having a hard time.

Thanks!

Comment: Before attempting to find roots you need to learn the basics of Mathematica syntax

Comment: The text of the question seems me very confusing. Probably a part of the text has been removed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function you want is `FindInstance`. For the second one, `FindInstance` takes ages and ages, so I also specified a range to search in, and it works instantly then.

```
FindInstance[x Tan[x] == 1. && x \[Element] Reals, x, 5]

FindInstance[
 Sin[Pi x]^2 - x^2 Cos[Pi x] == x && x \[Element] Reals && 0 < x < 10,
 x,
 5
] // N
```

Comment: Curious. The second takes a few seconds on Mma 9 without any range restriction `FindInstance[Sin[Pi x]^2 - x^2 Cos[Pi x] == x, x, 5] // N`

Comment: Bizarre. Adding the $x \in \mathbb{R}$ restriction makes it take much longer for me on 10.2.